# Materialise row-number column

Tags: sql-server-2012

On Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I would like to materialise the result of the `row_number` function, because I hope it makes queries running faster. I considered to make a view index, or to add a persisted computed column to the relevant table. I fail with both. How can I achieve what I want?

As example, let us look at an address table with multiple addresses per person.

#### View index

```
create view nrview with schemabinding as
select
  row_number() over (
    partition by person_id
    order by valid_from) nr,
  address_id,
  person_id,
  valid_from
from address

create unique clustered index ix
on nrview (
  address_id,
  nr,
  valid_from,
  person_id)
```

This fails with error message 10143:

> Cannot create index on view "mydatabase.dbo.nrview" because it contains a ranking or aggregate window function. Remove the function from the view definition or, alternatively, do not index the view.

#### Computed column

```
alter table address
add nr as
  row_number() over (
    partition by person_id
    order by valid_from) 
  persisted
```

This fails with the error message 4108:

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: No, as the error messages state, you can't persist it - unless you use, say, a trigger. Which means you'll have to essentially update the whole table (or at least every row for the affected `person_id` value(s)) every time any row is changed, added or deleted. I suggest you optimize elsewhere before assuming this will make queries faster. For example, why not post the table structure, indexes, and an actual post-execution plan where you believe `ROW_NUMBER()` is the main problem? I bet an index change will solve that better than persisting the result of the expression.

Comment: I belive `row_number` is my main problem because creating a table instead of a view and indexing it, as above, reduces the query time from hours to seconds. (And I don’t this is just a matter of indexes. Also in the original query, only indexes very used, no table scans, and no sorting had to be done in the execution.)

Comment: I think you're jumping to a lot of conclusions. The query was different by hours, really, to provide this row_number at runtime? You sure it wasn't being blocked?

Comment: The original query consistently takes hours to complete, so I exclude a locking issue. I concur this speed-up is unusual. I assume the engine has some problem with it, but: the materialisation definitely “makes queries running faster.”

Comment: Ok, so can you show an actual, post-execution plan for the query that takes hours, along with the same for the fast version that uses a materialized table? No select query should take hours to complete unless it's blocked or has infinite recursion. Your logic of why blocking can't be involved doesn't make sense to me - did you actually CHECK for blocking?

Comment: What purpose does the row number serve within the application?

Comment: Is addess_id the primary key of address?

Comment: Transferred to the example, `address_id` and `valid_from` together makes the primary key. `address_id` and `nr` are used for joins (up to two tables, each of them joined twice). The query is the spirit of finding a change in the address when at the same time there is a change in the other table, whereas “change” means a new row for that address_id with `old.nr=new.nr-1`.